# insert Facebook interstitial ads into react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads) in my react-native app (I've never used facebookAds) for inserting an Interstitial Ads.

This is what I've done in one of my app component (after `react-native install react-native-fbads`):

```
import { InterstitialAdManager } from 'react-native-fbads';

constructor(props) {
     InterstitialAdManager.showAd(XXXXX_XXXXX)  // this is line 16
    .then(didClick => {console.log("clicked")})
    .catch(error => {console.log("error")})
}
```

but I keep get this error: `Identifier directly after number(16:49)`.
My **placementId** has an underscore in the middle (i.e. 12345_6789), is it correct?

Comment: are you using the string `'12345_6789'` or plain number `12345_6789`? If the latter then that will be why you get an error. If the ID contains more than numbers, it will need to be a string.

Comment: I'm using plain number. I already tried with '12345_6789' and "12345_6789" but I got this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CTKInterstitialAdManager.showAd')

Comment: That would be a completely different error then. The error in your question  is because the ID needs to be a string since it contains an `_`. You should create a new question with the above error since you seem to have solved the original by using a string.